# Issues while matching a regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to split a string

```
Change 709131 on 2014/06/05 by person1

    - some description

Change 709081 on 2014/06/05 by person2

    more description

Change 708930 on 2014/06/04 by person3

    description xyz


Change 708906 on 2014/06/04 by person4

    description of change
```

I want to split from `Change \d+` (it means Change 709081 etc).

I am trying this with

```
set abc [regexp -inline -all {Change \d+\son.*Change \d+\son} $oIfs]
```

I am not getting the desired output

Edited : One way I found out is

```
set abc [regexp -inline -all {Change.*?(?=Change)} $oIfs]
```

But it is not giving the last part of the statement.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Try: `{Change.*?(?=Change|$)}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this construct:

```
Change \d+(?:(?!\mChange\M).)+
```

`(?:(?!Change).)+` will match any character except the word `Change`.

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/qtRcIjjj)

Comment: Its not splitting the string. It is adding whole string into first index

Comment: @Nitesh Oh oops. Bad habit, I shouldn't have put `\b` in there. It should be `\m` and `\M`. (Tcl uses those two instead of `\b`)

Answer (score 1):

Tcllib to the rescue: http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil_split.html

```
package require textutil::split

set s {Change 709131 on 2014/06/05 by person1

    - some description

Change 709081 on 2014/06/05 by person2

    more description

Change 708930 on 2014/06/04 by person3

    description xyz


Change 708906 on 2014/06/04 by person4

    description of change}

foreach {chg desc} [lrange [textutil::split::splitx $s {(Change \d+)}] 1 end] {lappend changes "$chg$desc"}

set i 0
foreach chg $changes {puts "[incr i]> $chg"}
```

```
1> Change 709131 on 2014/06/05 by person1

    - some description


2> Change 709081 on 2014/06/05 by person2

    more description

3> Change 708930 on 2014/06/04 by person3

    description xyz



4> Change 708906 on 2014/06/04 by person4

    description of change
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with your problem is to process the data line-by-line and build up a "record". When you encounter the start of a record, do something with the previous record, then reset (i.e. build a new record). Here is some suggested code:

```
set data {Change 709131 on 2014/06/05 by person1

    - some description

Change 708906 on 2014/06/04 by person4

    description of change
}

proc do_something {record} {
    # Process a record, in this case, just print it out with separators
    if {[llength $record] == 0} { return }

    puts "----------------"
    foreach line $record {
        puts $line
    }
}

set record [list]
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    if {[regexp {^Change \d+} $line]} {
        # Encounter the start of a record, process the previous record
        # and start a new record
        do_something $record
        set record [list]
    }
    lappend record "$line"
}

# Process the last record
if {[llength $record] != 0} { do_something $record }
```

Comment: Since `record` is a list, `{$record != ""}` seems like the wrong test.

Comment: Thank you Glenn. I blame it on my laziness and cut/paste skill: I originally designed `record` as a string buffer, then changed to a list of lines. I fixed the first `if`, but forgot to do so for the second.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a tricky regular expression, but it works with your sample data:

```
regexp -all -inline {(?w)^Change.*?(?:\Z|\n(?=Change))} $sampleData
```

Looking at the pieces of the RE itself:

```
(?w)             # "Weird" mode; ^ and $ are line anchored but . matches newlines
^Change          # "Change" at the start of a line...
.*?              # and as few extra characters as possible, until...
(?:              #   (start non-capturing group)
  \Z             # ... the end of the whole string...
|                # or...
  \n             # ... newline, followed by...
  (?=Change)     # ... "Change" (as zero-width lookahead)
)                #   (end non-capturing group)
```

Using your sample data:

```
% regexp -all -inline {(?w)^Change.*?(?:\Z|\n(?=Change))} $sampleData
{Change 709131 on 2014/06/05 by person1

    - some description

} {Change 709081 on 2014/06/05 by person2

    more description

} {Change 708930 on 2014/06/04 by person3

    description xyz


} {Change 708906 on 2014/06/04 by person4

    description of change}
```

Looks OK to me. Assuming nobody's putting the word “`Change`” directly at the start of the line in the descriptions.

Comment: `(?w)` is black magic, [documented](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M93) black magic. This is the first time I have _ever_ needed it! Congratulations on helping me explore the power of Tcl…